# Javascript I18n add custom locale

Tags: javascript, internationalization

I want to add a new locale to js intl api (NumberFormatter, DateFormatter), I have googled it but I could not find any useful information.
can anyone please guide me to the right direction or an API reference maybe

Answer (score 1):

You can't, unless you write a complete shim.

The implementations of the Intl functionality for all major browsers is on top of [ICU4C](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/icu4c/).
And that uses data from [CLDR](https://cldr.unicode.org/).

To add a new locale without a shim the locale would have to get into CLDR, then into ICU, and then into the browser.
You can do it on your machine, but it is (of course) not portable.

What locale do you want to add?

Locales might be "missing" at several levels:

- it is not in CLDR
- it is in CLDR, but not yet in ICU
- it is in CLDR/ICU, but a browser removed it to reduce size

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, Persian locale needs some changes to the DateFormatter (at least) for it to become truly localized! I wanted to make those changes. Month and weekday names need to change, and the dates year, month, day order is different in Persian when printed, and some very minor ones.

Comment: Can you elaborate about what that shim would look like ?
Turns out I really need a complete Locale for fictional languages that won't ever be supported :/