# Custom ECMA Intl Locale for fictional language

Tags: javascript, localization, internationalization, idioms, intl

## TL;DR

I'd love to define once(/use everywhere) some custom [Intl objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl) but I don't know if it's possible or if there is a good way to go at all ...

I need to use various custom (fictional) locales with tons of weird rules in the fields of:

- DateTimeFormat
- Collation
- UPPERCASE/lowercase correspondences *(this one will be the weirdest and is the **most important**)*
- segmentation
- plural-rules

## Long version (boring )

I have a project that will use various fictional languages in a fictional world and the user will be allowed to travel from places to places with currencies/dateTimes/and such and a need to interact with local people in their own language/customs to solve puzzles and riddles and whatnot.

I don't want to reinvent a local system for this game when Intl looks like the way to go, but is this even possible tho ?

So far I went through the documentation of [Intl](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl) but found close to nothing about how to do *(and use)* my own ones ...

*Note that my languages don't exist, never will, are not meant to, and won't ever have rules that resemble any existing language (I can't do a patchwork of existing languages rules, or at least I don't see why and don't think that would be a good idea)*

Comment: [shim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68985374/javascript-i18n-add-custom-locale)

Comment: Do you mean hot-replacing underlying elements of `Intl` and `String` to cram in my few new locales in a very hackish polyfill-like approach ?  
(just to be sure)

Comment: Not sure. The minute I spent on this suggest you cannot do this in a simple add a new locale way